# Displaying content in different ways

Tags: views, panels, theming

I sort of ran into a problem here, for a new project a piece of the homepage can have different layouts.

For example:

```
-----------------
| N  |    C     |
| E  |    O     |
| W  |    N     |
| S  |    T     |
|    |    E     |
|    |    N     |
|    |    T     |
-----------------
```

or

```
-----------------
|       C       |
|       O       |
|       N       |
|       T       |
|       E       |
|       N       |
|       T       |
-----------------
```

or

```
-----------------
|               |
|     NEWS      |
|               |
-----------------
```

So there are 3 types of layouts, news + content, just content and just news.
What would be the best way to do this? Currently I'm using Panels to build the homepage, this is just a small part of it.

It also would have to be very convenient for the user to switch styles, any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I kind of lost track of this issue.

What I ended up doing was using an extra custom field as a class selector, that way I was able to use javascript to show or adjust different part of the content.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) and [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) to build a different layout flexible and custom layout in your theme.
2. You can also build a custom theme with there layouts and switch the layout home page based on context. If you are planning for theme, you can write a subtheme for [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega), a HTML5 base theme, or can you choose the best base theme as per your need.

Comment: Thanks, but none of those are what I'm looking for. Would there be a way to create a new content type with a select list for the layout, and use this value as a class/id selector on my Panel? In that case I can solve it all with CSS.

Comment: Context module lets you define contexts based on different criteria. As a reaction to these criteria, the module can add a css class to the body element.

Comment: I used context before, but I can't select a node from a specific content type and then use a value for the body class. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Homebox](http://drupal.org/project/homebox) module allows you to manage the layout which you show in the Graphics. This is also implemented in [Drupal's](http://drupal.org) official website. In this users can also have choice to disable/enable blocks.

So you can create two blocks:

News and Content. Add this blocks to homebox.